# Is it possible to import from two files with the same name?

Tags: python, import

I have these files:

```
/somewhere/file.py
/elsewhere/file.py
/completeley/different/place/main.py
```

Now, within `main.py` I need stuff from the other files, in pseudocode:

```py
from "/somewhere/file.py" import function_1
from "/elsewhere/file.py" import function_2
```

Can Python handle this? How?

Note that the trick of placing the empty `__init__.py` file cannot be used here (or at least I don't know how, also don't want to convert the whole file system into a Python package), and using `sys.path.insert` also fails because the two files have the same name.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
from somewhere.file import function_1
from somewhere_else.file import function_2
```

If you want to import the modules

```
import somewhere.file as file_a
import somewhere_else.file as file_b
```